# How can I transform XML to invalid XML using XSLT?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, ofx

I need to transform a valid XML document to the [OFX v1.0.2 format](http://www.ofx.net/OFXExamplesPage/OFXExamples.aspx).  This format is more or less XML, but it's technically invalid and therefore cannot be parsed as XML.

I'm having trouble getting my Xml transformation working because the .Net `XslCompiledTransform` object insists on interpreting the output as an XML document (which is fair enough).

**Here's my function to transform the Xml

```
public string Transform(XmlElement xmlElement, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
{
    string strReturn = "";

    // Set the settings to allow scripts to executed.
    XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings(false, true);

    // Load the XSLT Document
    XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();

    xslt.Load(xsltFileName, settings, new XmlUrlResolver());

    // arguments
    XsltArgumentList args = new XsltArgumentList();
    if (parameters != null && parameters.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (string key in parameters.Keys)
        {
            args.AddParam(key, "", parameters[key]);
        }
    }

    //Create a memory stream to write to
    Stream objStream = new MemoryStream();

    // Transform the xml/xslt into a Writer
    XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(objStream, Encoding.UTF8);

    // Apply the transform
    xslt.Transform(xmlElement, args, xmlWriter);

    objStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    // Read the contents of the stream
    StreamReader objSR = new StreamReader(objStream);

    strReturn = objSR.ReadToEnd();

    return strReturn;
}
```

If I escape the xml-ish tags using `&lt;` and `&gt`, they get removed when I download the file.

**Here's the start of my XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"></xsl:output>
  <xsl:param name="currentdate"></xsl:param>
  <xsl:template match="Transactions">
OFXHEADER:100
DATA:OFXSGML
VERSION:102
SECURITY:NONE
ENCODING:USASCII
CHARSET:1252
COMPRESSION:NONE
OLDFILEUID:NONE
NEWFILEUID:NONE
<OFX>
    <SIGNONMSGSRSV1>
        <SONRS>
            <STATUS>
                <CODE>0
                <SEVERITY>INFO
            </STATUS>
            <DTSERVER><xsl:value-of select="$currentdate" />
            <LANGUAGE>ENG
```

**So can I transform my XML to a plain text string?**

**UPDATE:**

I've changed this question.  I just realised the obvious answer to the original question.  Using the `XslCompiledTransform` object requires me to write the output to an Xml document using an XmlTextWriter.  Obviously it won't parse.  Apologies.

Comment: You should do a better job of saying what exactly the problem is. In particular, can you create a small example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @John - I'll update the question to include the exception and some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xslt can output text; just make sure that you set the output-mode of the xslt to text, and wriet to a `TextWriter` (there are multiple overloads available). Writing something that is *nearly* xml in xslt is painful, but possible with disabling the escape rules.

Here's an example (albeit ugly) xslt for writing non-xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:call-template name="startElement">
        <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'SONRS'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>        
      <xsl:call-template name="startElement">
        <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'STATUS'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="0"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:call-template name="startElement">
        <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'SEVERITY'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="'INFO'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:call-template name="endElement">
        <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'SONRS'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="startElement">
    <xsl:param name="name"/>
    <xsl:param name="value"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="endElement">
    <xsl:param name="name"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Marc - the answer became rather obvious when I worked out I was serializing it using an XmlWriter... :)

Comment: Thanks for that update too, Marc.  That is going to end up being one hell of an xslt!
I'm thinking it might be worth my while just doing this all with a stringbuilder...

Comment: @Damovisa - It may well be easier. Note that you could also use `XmlWriter` and `WriteRaw`